# To do list in Javascript - How to always insert the new item on top of the list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a to do list, that looks similar to this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_todo

The user is supposed to type in a task so that it will be added to the list. Unlike the one i linked to, i want the newest input to always be on the top of the list, instead of being added at the bottom. I've tried using the insertbefore() function, but i don't know how to make it work

Here's my code:

```js
tasks = [];

function addTask() {

  var li = document.createElement("li");

  // Adding checkbox
  var cbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
  cbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  li.appendChild(cbox);
  cbox.setAttribute('id', 'box');

  // Adding thing to do
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
  var task = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(task);

  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  }

  // Part 3
  tasks.push(newTask.value);

  document.getElementById("newTask").value = '';
}



// Prevent Default
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffe699;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

fieldset {
  background: skyblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#box {
  margin: 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1> To do list </h1>

<form class="" action="todo.html" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <label> Add a task in the input field below </label> <br><br>
    <input id="newTask" type="text" placeholder="Type a task here" autofocus> <br><br>
    <input id="submit" onclick="addTask()" type="submit" value="Add task"><br><br>
    <output name="result"> Hallo </output>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<h2>List of things to do</h2>

<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of appening the the child, like so

```
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
```

just insert it before the first child

like this:

```
var list = document.getElementById("myList");
list.insertBefore(newItem, list.childNodes[0]);
```

there is a very clear example that you can follow here:

[Example link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_insertbefore)

Comment: I've seen an example like that, but in that instance you just put it above the same item every time, don't you? In my case, the item on the top changes every time. For instance, if that list is 1. Coffee 2. Tea, and you want to add Soda and then Gin, won't it say 1. Soda 2. Gin. 3 Coffee 4. Tea, instead of 1. Gin 2. Soda 3. Coffee 4.  Tea?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is only a matter of presentation, I would change the `<ul>` into a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and display the task list in reverse order using [flex-direction: column-reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction).

```js
tasks = [];

function addTask() {

  var li = document.createElement("li");

  // Adding checkbox
  var cbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
  cbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  li.appendChild(cbox);
  cbox.setAttribute('id', 'box');

  // Adding thing to do
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
  var task = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(task);

  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
  }

  // Part 3
  tasks.push(newTask.value);

  document.getElementById("newTask").value = '';
}



// Prevent Default
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffe699;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /* Added */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse; 
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

fieldset {
  background: skyblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#box {
  margin: 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1> To do list </h1>

<form class="" action="todo.html" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <label> Add a task in the input field below </label> <br><br>
    <input id="newTask" type="text" placeholder="Type a task here" autofocus> <br><br>
    <input id="submit" onclick="addTask()" type="submit" value="Add task"><br><br>
    <output name="result"> Hallo </output>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<h2>List of things to do</h2>

<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about that. Did you only change the css? Thanks anyways!

Comment: @HankMoody Yes only added two lines in the CSS

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new element to the top of an array:

```
tasks.unshift(new_element);
```

Insert an element to the first position inside a parent element:

```
parent_element.insertBefore(new_element, parent_element.firstChild);
```

*Note that if `parent_element` is empty, `parent_element.firstChild` will be `null`, and `insertBefore` method will act like `appendChild` method.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use insert before in the "else" part**

```js
tasks = [];

function addTask() {

  var li = document.createElement("li");

  // Adding checkbox
  var cbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
  cbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  li.appendChild(cbox);
  cbox.setAttribute('id', 'box');

  // Adding thing to do
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
  var task = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(task);
  
  
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");                              
  }
  else {
   var ullist = document.getElementById("list");
    ullist.insertBefore(li, ullist.childNodes[0]);
  }

  // Part 3
  tasks.push(newTask.value);

  document.getElementById("newTask").value = '';
}



// Prevent Default
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function(){
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffe699;
  font-family: garamond;
  font-size: 20px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

fieldset {
  background: skyblue;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

ul li:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#box {
  margin: 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> To do list </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1> To do list </h1>

    <form class="" action="todo.html" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <label> Add a task in the input field below </label> <br><br>
        <input id="newTask" type="text" placeholder="Type a task here" autofocus> <br><br>
        <input id="submit" onclick="addTask()" type="submit" value="Add task"><br><br>
        <output name="result"> Hallo </output>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

    <h2>List of things to do</h2>

    <ul id="list">
    </ul>


    <script src="todo.js"> </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
tasks = [];

function addTask() {

  var li = document.createElement("li");

  // Adding checkbox
  var cbox = document.createElement('INPUT');
  cbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
  li.appendChild(cbox);
  cbox.setAttribute('id', 'box');

  // Adding thing to do
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("newTask").value;
  var task = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(task);

  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("list").insertBefore(li, document.getElementById("list").childNodes[0]);
  }

  // Part 3
  tasks.push(newTask.value);

  document.getElementById("newTask").value = '';
}



// Prevent Default
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 600 px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffe699;
  font - family: garamond;
  font - size: 20 px;
}

ul {
  list - style - type: none;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2 px solid black;
}

ul li {
  padding - top: 15 px;
  padding - bottom: 15 px;
  font - weight: bold;
}

fieldset {
  background: skyblue;
  border: 2 px solid black;
}

ul li: nth - child(odd) {
  background - color: skyblue;
}

ul li: nth - child(even) {
  background - color: white;
}

ul li: hover {
  background - color: aqua;
}

# box {
  margin: 0 px 20 px 0 px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> To do list </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1> To do list </h1>

  <form class="" action="todo.html" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <label> Add a task in the input field below </label> <br><br>
      <input id="newTask" type="text" placeholder="Type a task here" autofocus> <br><br>
      <input id="submit" onclick="addTask()" type="submit" value="Add task"><br><br>
      <output name="result"> Hallo </output>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <h2>List of things to do</h2>

  <ul id="list">
  </ul>


  <script src="todo.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just type:

```
document.getElementById("list").prepend(li);
```

- appendChild() add element at the end.
- prepend() add element on the
  top.

Sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/zpsw54ag/3/

You can read here for more information:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend